# Have problem with catkin tutorials

Tags: ros, catkin, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
I following the ros tutorial but when i do tutorial no 3 and no 4, at some point the ubuntu show me this error
(The specified source space "/home/ros/catkin_ws/my_src" does not exist).
can somebody help me with this error

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198926/have-problem-with-catkin-tutorials/) by [ghost](https://answers.ros.org/users/21020/ghost/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-12-04**:
Please state what exactly you are doing, i.e. what commands did you perform, what is your directory structure, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is your user named "ros"? If not, you should verify this. Please provide more detail. Copy and paste relevant terminal output and edit your question.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1